# What assumptions should be made?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, analysis, derivatives

take a problem like

A trough is 12 feet long and 3 feet across. Its ends are isosceles triangles with altitudes of 3 feet. 
Water is being pumped into the trough at 2 cubic feet per minute. How fast is the water level rising when the depth is 1 feet?

Which assumptions should be made before solving this?

Why do we make the **assumption that there is no leak in the trough?**

Is it because of the fact: that word problems provide **all** information about the existence of the objects? Thanks!

Comment: You're thinking about this too much. If the word problem doesn't say there is a leak, there isn't a leak.

Comment: @Andrey, thanks, I know I think too much (unfortunately). But so a word problem provides **all** information pre-hand? Which is why if no leak is mentioned, there is no leak? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it would be safe to assume a word problem contains all the relevant information needed to solve it.

Had there been a leak, it would need to tell you how quick the leak is draining the trough, but since it doesn't, it is safe to assume that there is no leak.